# Change build pipeline behavior based on branch

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have a build pipeline on Azure DevOps that creates a package when the build runs successfully.

I would like to change behavior if the build is run from another git branch, for example when we run it from master build a release package but when we run it from a dev or feature branch release a prerelease package.

I think I will need to use variables and some condition checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [predefined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) variable `Build.SourceBranch` and use a [custom condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in the package task:

```
steps:
- task: Create a release package
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
- task: Create a pre-release package
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/dev'))
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a step in the right direction.  I will now try and add a ps step to set the prerelease variable using  "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"

Comment: fyi: i created an inline ps step in my build pipleline wich sets the prerelease variable to -beta and added your condition to it. Everything is how i want it now.